# Calling OpenCV python script with php page

Tags: php, python, linux, opencv, anaconda

I am trying to run a Python Script for Image Detection Via a php page and to catch and display the output generated by py script.

Here is my python script [GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_License_Plate_Recognition_Python/blob/master/Main.py)

I am running the python script using this code :

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo python Main.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

This is producing this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

****But the same script works fine when executed independently with terminal.
I have used anaconda for installation of Opencv****

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you typing the same command while executing the script independently in terminal?

Comment: Yes I am using the same.

Comment: And do you have a virtual environment for it?

Comment: No I am not using Virtual environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anaconda creates separate environment so you need to start your script using python copy from that enviroment

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo /home/path_to_anacondad_env/python Main.py');
```

Comment: Thanks, I was totally unaware of that

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me, I installed openCV with pip install but when I ran it from php I couldn't find it, but I found that I only have to install it globally with this command: sudo apt-get install python3-opencv
I restarted Apache and that worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).